# How to create Combobox Handler activating when i chose data in combo in GTK#

Tags: c#, combobox, gtk#

I have few items in combo box, and 10 entry fields. Each item in combo box is "connected" to objct, and when i chose first item from combo box it should fill entries with data from objct number 1, when i chose second item it should use data from object 2...

To check what item in combo box is selected i using:IdFieldComboBox.Active;
but i need to call it all time, selection is changed. What i should use to do that?

for now i use foucs handler but its not correct solution:

```
    protected void OnIdFieldComboBoxFocusChildSet (object o, Gtk.FocusChildSetArgs args)
{

    unitNumber = IdFieldComboBox.Active;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I found the right [GTK# ComboBox documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aGtk.ComboBox), it is already spelled out for you.  The sample has you using `GetActiverIter` which returns True/False on whether it is found, and if found, outputs the value to the TreeIter object passed in as an out.

```
 using System;
 using Gtk;
 class ComboBoxSample
 {
      static void Main ()
      {
           new ComboBoxSample ();
      }
      ComboBoxSample ()
      {
           Application.Init ();
           Window win = new Window ("ComboBoxSample");
           win.DeleteEvent += new DeleteEventHandler (OnWinDelete);
           ComboBox combo = ComboBox.NewText ();
           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
                combo.AppendText ("item " + i);
           combo.Changed += new EventHandler (OnComboBoxChanged);
           win.Add (combo);
           win.ShowAll ();
           Application.Run ();
      }
      void OnComboBoxChanged (object o, EventArgs args)
      {
           ComboBox combo = o as ComboBox;
           if (o == null)
                return;
           TreeIter iter;
           if (combo.GetActiveIter (out iter))
                Console.WriteLine ((string) combo.Model.GetValue (iter, 0));
      }
      void OnWinDelete (object obj, DeleteEventArgs args)
      {
           Application.Quit ();
      }
 }
```